# Google App Engine Channel API Javascript Client: Set Poll Timer Manually

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, polling, channel-api

I am writing a web client that supports messages sent from a Google App Engine Java server, by using Google's official GAE Channel API Javascript client. I would like to know if it is possible for me to manually set the timer for the frequency of polls by my client to the server for new messages from a channel.

I wish to use a slower timer between client polls because I'm trying to debug the messages being returned to the client by using a browser inspection tool, such as Firefox's Firebug, and having lots of GET HTTP requests being sent out by the client's polls makes this difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On production the client uses long polling (ie Comet).  You shouldn't be seeing frequent polls.  Unfortunately it behaves differently on the dev_appserver, which does constant polling.

Unfortunately that doesn't help you.

I'd recommend using Chrome/Chromium, it doesn't spew every XHR GET request.